# Are arrays not considered containers because they are not based off of a class?

Tags: c++, containers

Is an array a container?

Arrays hold a set of elements of the same type in a contiguous memory location so, do they not qualify as containers?

Comment: In most languages, an array would indeed qualify as a container. However, you provide no context of language via tagging or in your question, so it is currently quite unclear. Arrays are different things in different languages.

Comment: I meant in c++. I failed to clarify that

Comment: AFAIK, an array by itself is not really considered a container in C++'s eyes. It is just a chunk of memory. However, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a real container that wraps a dynamic array, and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a real container that wraps a static array.

Comment: Please clarify *your* definition of *container*.  Fundamentally, an array is a contain since it contains things.  If may not be a smart container, but in my definition it is the basic container.

Answer (score 3):

In the standard; the language feature relating to arrays (i.e. the [C-style `int a[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) and not the [library `std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)) is seperate to the containers as defined in the library section, [[container.requirements.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#1);

> Containers are objects that store other objects. They control allocation and deallocation of these objects through constructors, destructors, insert and erase operations.

*Stricter requirements for each container type (or container concept) follow in later sections.*

As such, the language array is probably not strictly considered a "container", in a more informal sense, it may be.

They do share some level of common functionality and have some interchangability, such as the ability to make use of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` etc. A cursory example is `std::vector<>`, it was generally referred to as the container to be used as a "safe" array; to be used where a built in array may have previously been used.

Comment: As opposed to `std::array`?

Comment: Correct. That is defined as an container in the library section of the standard.

Comment: So what's the difference between std::array and array? Does array not come from this standard library? Is Std::array not the same as a normal array?

Comment: @Dog: That's correct. You don't need to include any header for `int arr[5]`. It's not associated with `namespace std` which means that `std::begin(arr)` cannot be called as `begin(arr)`. There's no `arr.size()`. etc etc.

Comment: @Dog. Basically, [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a wrapper around a [C-style array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array). It gives it the same/similar API as some of the other containers in the library. The difference is small, but significant for code expecting a standard library container (i.e. valid calls to the members `cont.begin()` etc. This is why I think technically a C-style array may not be a container, but in colloquial terms, it may be.

Comment: `std::array` is not a container either by that definition because it is not capable of inserting or erasing objects.

Comment: @nwp. The table for the containers doesn't explicitly list an `insert` or `erase` member; strictly speaking `std::array` partially satisfies the requirements (although the cppreference lists it as satisfying the "Container" requirement). Various containers concepts have more formal requirements. IIRC, C++17 will include a container concept "ContiguousContainer" and things may change things a little.

Comment: So wait, arr isn't associated with std, I get that, it doesn't have member functions like begin(). But why can't you do begin(arr)? But you can do std::begin(arr) because begin is a member function in std?

Comment: @Dog, because there is an overloaded function `begin` in the std namespace that accepts a C style array as an argument, see here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin, overload 2. ADL and `using` declarations aside.